# Format datetime string field to remove the trailing 'Z' character, and replace the 'T' character with a space

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, datetime-format

I would like to format the datetime field displayed in my header element. It is the startAt="2016-11-03T08:29:13Z" element in my xml.

Replace the 'T' with a space and remove the 'Z'.

This should be done using xsl, my code are as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:key name="party" match="newParty" use="@userId" />
    <xsl:template match="@timeShift">
        <xsl:attribute name="timeShift">
            <xsl:call-template name="format-duration"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="format-duration">
    <xsl:param name="value" select="." />
    <xsl:param name="alwaysIncludeHours" select="false()" />
    <xsl:param name="includeSeconds" select="true()" />
    <xsl:if test="$value > 3600 or $alwaysIncludeHours">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(format-number($value div 3600, '00'), ':')"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($value div 60 mod 60, '00')" />
    <xsl:if test="$includeSeconds">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(':', format-number($value mod 60, '00'))" />
    </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>  

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/chatTranscript">
        <html>
            <head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/webrecall/css/chat.css"/>
            </head>
            <header>Chat - <xsl:value-of select="@sessionId" /> - <xsl:value-of select="@startAt" /></header>

            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="newParty[userInfo/@userType='CLIENT']">
        <div class="ClientJoined" id="{@userId}">
            <label>Client: <xsl:value-of select="userInfo/@userNick" />
            </label>
            <label class="timeShiftLabel">
                <xsl:call-template name="format-duration">
                    <xsl:with-param name="value" select="@timeShift"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </label>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="newParty[userInfo/@userType='AGENT']">
        <div class="AgentJoined" id="{@userId}">
            <label>Agent: <xsl:value-of select="userInfo/@userNick" /></label>
            <label class="timeShiftLabel">
                <xsl:call-template name="format-duration"><xsl:with-param name="value" select="@timeShift"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </label>
        </div>
    </xsl:template> 
        <xsl:template match="newParty[userInfo/@userType='EXTERNAL']">
            <div class="SystemJoined" id="{@userId}">
                <label>System: <xsl:value-of select="userInfo/@userNick" /></label>
                <label class="timeShiftLabel System">
                    <xsl:call-template name="format-duration">
                        <xsl:with-param name="value" select="@timeShift"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </label>
            </div>
        </xsl:template> 
            <xsl:template match="message">
                <xsl:variable name="party-class">
                    <xsl:call-template name="lookup-class"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <div class="Messages {$party-class}" id="{@eventId}">
                    <label><xsl:value-of select="msgText" /></label>
                    <label class="timeShiftLabel">
                        <xsl:call-template name="format-duration">
                            <xsl:with-param name="value" select="@timeShift"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </xsl:template>   
            <xsl:template match="notice">
                <xsl:variable name="party-class">
                    <xsl:call-template name="lookup-class"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <div class="Notices {$party-class}" id="{@eventId}">
                    <label>
                        <xsl:value-of select="noticeText" />
                    </label>
                    <label class="timeShiftLabel">
                        <xsl:call-template name="format-duration">
                            <xsl:with-param name="value" select="@timeShift"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </xsl:template>
            <xsl:template match="partyLeft">
            <xsl:variable name="party-class">
                <xsl:call-template name="lookup-class"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <div class="Notices {$party-class}" id="{@eventId}">
                <label><xsl:value-of select="reason" /></label>
                <label class="timeShiftLabel">
                    <xsl:call-template name="format-duration">
                        <xsl:with-param name="value" select="@timeShift"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </label>
            </div>
            </xsl:template>
            <xsl:template name="lookup-class">
                <xsl:variable name="party-type" select="key('party', @userId)/userInfo/@userType" />
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$party-type='CLIENT'">Client</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$party-type='AGENT'">Agent</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$party-type='EXTERNAL'">System</xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:template>
        </xsl:stylesheet>
```

The input xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<chatTranscript startAt="2016-11-03T08:29:13Z" sessionId="0001KaC1NSN60019">

<newParty userId="0079581AF5590023" timeShift="0" visibility="ALL" eventId="1">
    <userInfo personId="" userNick="10.50.24.202" userType="CLIENT" protocolType="FLEX" timeZoneOffset="120"/>
    <userData>
        <item key="GMSServiceId">c0aa6221-d5f9-4fdc-9f75-ed63e99b1f12</item>
        <item key="IdentifyCreateContact">3</item><item key="MediaType">chat</item>
        <item key="TimeZone">120</item><item key="_data_id">139-9a8ee95b-d3ba-43a2-93a9-08ed7965d63d</item>
        <item key="firstName">Mike</item>
        <item key="lastName">Kumm</item>
    </userData>
</newParty>

<newParty userId="0079581AF56C0025" timeShift="20" visibility="ALL" eventId="2">
    <userInfo personId="1" userNick="allendei" userType="AGENT" protocolType="BASIC" timeZoneOffset="120"/>
</newParty>

<message userId="0079581AF56C0025" timeShift="32" visibility="ALL" eventId="4"><msgText treatAs="NORMAL">Hello</msgText></message>
<message userId="0079581AF5590023" timeShift="62" visibility="ALL" eventId="5"><msgText msgType="text" treatAs="NORMAL">Can you help me?</msgText></message>
```

The expected outcome is:

```
   <html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/webrecall/css/chat.css">
   </head>
   <header>Chat - 0001KaC1NSN60019 - 2016-11-03 08:29:13</header>
   <div class="ClientJoined" id="0079581AF5590023"><label>Client: 10.50.24.202</label><label class="timeShiftLabel">00:00</label></div>
   <div class="AgentJoined" id="0079581AF56C0025"><label>Agent: allendei</label><label class="timeShiftLabel">00:20</label></div>
   <div class="Messages Agent" id="4"><label>Hello</label><label class="timeShiftLabel">01:32</label></div>
   <div class="Messages Client" id="5"><label>Can you help me?</label><label class="timeShiftLabel">01:02</label></div>
</html>
```

Comment: Please reduce the example to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem - see [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot "format the datetime field" in XSLT 1.0, because XSLT 1.0 has no concept of dates, times or datetimes. All of these appear as meaningless strings to the XSLT 1.0 processor.

However, you can easily achieve the desired result by a simple string manipulation, using the `translate()` function:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate('2016-11-03T08:29:13Z', 'TZ', ' ')"/>
```

will return:

```
2016-11-03 08:29:13
```